# How to use non activeX content controllers in VBA for Microsoft word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to find a way to use the non-activeX content controllers in Microsoft word and creating a VBA macro for them.  For example a combo box.  I can not for the life of me figure out how to call them in my VBA script, as every time I get a runtime error 424.  I have named the combo box in its properties, but it does not seem to have the same affect as this does for the ActiveX Combo box.   I must be missing something extremely easy. Any help is really appreciated. I have placed example code below;

```
Private Sub Document_open()  'Auto Run Macros Upon Opening of this specific doc


Call ComboBox1Additems
Call ComboBox2Additems
Call ComboBox3Additems
Call ComboBox4Additems
Call ComboBox5Additems
Call ComboBox6Additems
Call ComboBox7Additems
Call ComboBox12_Change


End Sub

 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 'Running through possible ComboBox Values and Updating the Corrosoponding Text Box



If ComboBox1.Value = "TMS backup" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "The TMS installation directory, settings directory and the database was backed up before the update was performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "TMS installation" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Installation of version 1.17.X.19XXX performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "TMS update" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Update from version 1.16.X.XXXXX to version 1.17.X.19XXX performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Tool presetter update" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Update from version 1.16.X.XXXXX to version 1.17.X.19XXX performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Database generated" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Database structure created with version 1.17.0"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "article characteristic bar update" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Update of DIN 4000 and (CAM) structure to version 2.2.0 (DIN) and X.X.X (CAM)"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "CAM-Interface installation" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Installation of the version X.X.X and configuration of the (CAM) interface"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "CAM-Interface update" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Updated the (CAM) interface to version X.X.X"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "WebService installation" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Installation of version 1.1.116.2 and configuration of WebService performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "WebService update" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Update of WebService to version 1.1.116.2 performed"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "CodeMeter initialized" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Set up CodeMeter on the license server and the client machines"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    TextBox1.Value = "Please make a drop down selection or manually fill out if not applicable"

    Else

    TextBox1.Value = "Please make a drop down selection or manually fill out if not applicable"


End If

End Sub

Sub ComboBox1Additems() 'Adding Items to ActiveX Control Combo Boxes
ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox1.AddItem "TMS backup"
ComboBox1.AddItem "TMS installation"
ComboBox1.AddItem "TMS update"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Tool presetter update"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Database generated"
ComboBox1.AddItem "article characteristic bar update"
ComboBox1.AddItem "CAM-Interface installation"
ComboBox1.AddItem "CAM-Interface update"
ComboBox1.AddItem "WebService installation"
ComboBox1.AddItem "WebService update"
ComboBox1.AddItem "CodeMeter initialized"

End Sub


Sub ComboBox12_Change()
 ComboBox12.AddItem "Turkey"
 ComboBox12.AddItem "Chicken"
 ComboBox12.AddItem "Duck"
 ComboBox12.AddItem "Goose"
 ComboBox12.AddItem "Grouse"
End Sub
```

The ComboBox#Additems() when called run fine upon, these are pointing at activeX comboboxes.  Combobox12_change() gives an error Runtime error "424", object required when run. This is "pointing" at a non-activeX combobox.

Comment: If you already know the values (the code you show is static) why not assign them to the content controls at design time?

Comment: From my understanding this is not possible for the active X Contentcontrols, I have also tried this by just creating the values manually inside of the non active X content controls.  My issue is that I can not get value checking to work like I have it for the non active x content controls (combobox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those controls are named [ContentControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrols)

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ccs As ContentControls,cc as ContentControl
Set ccs= Me.ActiveWindow.Document.ContentControls
For Each cc In ccs
  If cc.Title = "myTitle" Then
    MsgBox cc.DropdownListEntries(1)
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

On Document_open event those controols may not be ready.

Comment: So im not sure if I am following your response.  I know that these are called content controls.  I would like this to happen without a button press.  Are you saying  the Document_open is the wrong place to call these functions?

Comment: @ChesterS.not sure about Document_Open, try it. See my code how to reference those controls. They don't have a named property like ActiveX controls. You have to loop through the`ContentControls`collection and identify them by title.

Comment: I see, I will try this when I get a chance today or tomorrow.  Thank you for the help on this as well!

Comment: So I got it going now and was able to succesfully add an item to the drop down.  Now I just need to figure out how to check the value for the drop down parameters and do an If value = this than "text Box" = this.  This question has been answered.  Thank you again for the help!